# Getting compiler error at making basic sum

Tags: c++, sum

I'm new to this community and hope someone out there can help me. I just recently started to learn c++ and still don't get much.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Which sum do you wanna do?" << endl;
    cout << "Introduce your first number";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "The second number?";
    cin >> num2;

    int sum = num1 + num2;
    cout "The result is" << sum;
}
```

I always get this error:

> error: expected ';' before string constant

Comment: `cout "the result is" << sum;` doesnt have "<<"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things:

1. you have already declared the integer variable "sum". So you don't need to say `int sum = num1 + num2` - just saying `sum = num1 + num2` is enough
2. `cout<< "The result is "<< sum;` (you forgot "<<" after cout)

Comment: Thanks, now it's working. So if I wouldn't had the "int sum = 0" the int would be necessary?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Could you be a little more specific? Also is c++ your first programming language? If so start with something more friendly like python. Python is great

Answer (score 0):

cout **<<** "The result is" << sum;

Comment: You miss the <<

Comment: Thanks, that was one fail. Still getting and error.

Line 15 which is the -> int sum =...

with error "error: redeclaration of 'int sum'"

Comment: Here:  int sum = num1 + num2;
Just delete the "int" part . Because you dont need it as you have declared once at the beginning.

Comment: You can thumb up my answer if it was helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you missed:

1. sum is declared twice
2. `cout "the result is" << sum` should be `cout << "the result is" << sum`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this community and hope someone out there can help me. I just recently started to learn c++ and still don't get much.

```
//int num1;
```

// int num2;
  // int sum = 0;

//int sum = num1 + num2;
//cout "The result is" << sum;

the main issue i noticed is you double assigned the sum variable. just delete the int sum = 0; or replace it with int sum;